# Download bit array image not work on IOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, iphone, html, webview

I have one page that renders one byte array image from api service.

This works fine, and i can download it from bowser and works in my web view for android, but not work download in my web view on IOS Device.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't download an image directly from a webview. The user must long press the image and then manually select save image.

Comment: @EritonSilva iOS is way more locked down then Android. Apple just doesn't allow you to download whatever you want. You could implement this in your app, and ask for Photo Library permissions, but that's about it.